# Pinout for lcd screen without datasheet

Tags: oled

I found an oled screen at work, that I want to use, but it doesn't have a datasheet, just has its model number printed on the back, it is P19702. The only thing that I found online was this:http://www.spelistopto.com.tw/index.php/en/application-products/item/22-no19-p19702

I was wondering if someone knew anything about this oled screen, or what the general rule is to find the pinout for an oled screen.

Comment: Try doing searches for other displays of the same technology and resolution, possibly with the same type of connector.  Also see what you can learn about the SSD1303 controller chip mentioned at your link.

Comment: Try make detailed photo of back side where is visible layout and some other components especially if there is 12V converter for Vcc and what everything is there.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that inside your module is this OLED panel: [USMP-P19701.pdf](https://d3c4anv3uqsmm5.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/datasheets/USMP-P19701.pdf)

With this driver: [SSD1303](http://www.mapele.co.jp/files/attachment/594/SSD1303.pdf)

Try analyze schematic of your module, you can found there also 13V boost converter and some blocking capacitors.